# Shortcode displaying the product name and price in WooCommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I need to show product title and current price via shortcode in the product page without using product id.

I mean my code with automatically detect product id from current product page where i use shortcode and get the title and price.

For example this one, I have to use the specific id inside shortcode like this [iw_product_price id=''] to show product price.

```php
// Get WooCommerce product price by ID via shortcode: [iw_product_price id='']
function iw_product_price_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );

    $html = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
        $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        $html = $_product->get_price_html();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'iw_product_price', 'iw_product_price_shortcode' );

// Get WooCommerce product name by ID via shortcode: [iw_product_name id='']
function iw_product_name_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );

    $html = '';

    if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
        $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
        $html = $_product->get_title();
    }
    return $html; 
} 
add_shortcode( 'iw_product_name', 'iw_product_name_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Where is your code attempt?

Comment: In function.php

For example, I have to use the specific id inside shortcode like this [iw_product_price id=''] to show product price. i need to get id automatically if i input in any product page. 

function iw_product_price_shortcode( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => null,
), $atts, 'bartag' );

$html = '';

if( intval( $atts['id'] ) > 0 && function_exists( 'wc_get_product' ) ){
    $_product = wc_get_product( $atts['id'] );
    $html = $_product->get_price_html();
}
return $html;
}
add_shortcode( 'iw_product_price', 'iw_product_price_shortcode' );

Comment: get_queried_object_id() will return current post id. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shortcode will detect the product ID (or the product Object) and will display the product name with the formatted product price in WooCommerce product pages:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_name_price', 'get_product_name_price_shortcode' );
function get_product_name_price_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'product_name_price' ) );
    
    global $product;

    $is_a_product =  is_a($product, 'WC_Product');
    
    if( ! $is_a_product  && 'product' ===  get_post_type( $id )  ){
        $product = wc_get_product( $id ); // get the product object from the ID
    } 
    if ( $is_a_product ) {
        return '<span class="product-name">' . $product->get_name() . '</span> <br>' .
        $product->get_price_html();
    }
}
```

Usage as a simple shortcode: `[product_name_price]`

Usage as a shortcode using the product ID argument: `[product_name_price id='28']`

Comment: Thank you, its working. But the problem is your shortcode shows name and price into one line.

Can you help to to use name and price shortcode separately. 

Product name is [product_name] and price is [product_price]